# Pentaho Text file out separator

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I am using a `Text file output` step in Pentaho Kettle for extracting data from sql and putting into CSV files. I have specified comma as the content separator. But sometimes I receive the files with semicolon seperated values. Any body else has faced the issue? I have read semicolon seperated values is the default content seperator for CSV file formats. I believe the content seperator is set to default to semicolon. Is this because the content seperator is set to default by the spoon environment based on the input data?

Answer (score 1):

open the text file output step, go to content tab, their you will find option called Separator their what ever you will specify it will come into your final result, by-default you will find semi-column over their so just change it to comma and your problem will get resolved...

Comment: Is there a way to create a transformation to test the output file is comma seperated or Semi colon seperated?

Comment: you can use preview the transformation step instead of directly running it and check value at particular step in transformation.

Comment: My job is a scheduled one. Runs on a particular day. I want to make this automated. If the files are not comma seperated, I want to abort the process.

Comment: i can give you directanswer but that will not be fair, do some analysis you will get your answer directly.. Still you can use data validator step for checking the value's of filters according to your requirement.

Comment: Data validator step is for validating values in specific columns of a file. I understand. Since this is about file properties right. I am just exploring other possible ways to identify the content separator of a file